# Android ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException

Tags: android, android-asynctask, adapter

I create a AsyncTask and parse JSON and in background i put it to List, and my app have errors, i can't understand what  to do? This error when my app create!!! 
Парсю JSON и кидаю его в Лист с Массивом и приложение крашится

```
 List<Row> result = new ArrayList<Row>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        try {
        result.add(new Row(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("thumbnail")));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Row> result) {
        adapter.clear();
        adapter.add(result);
    }
```

**Row.java**

```
class Row implements Parcelable{

         public final Creator<Row> CREATOR = new Creator<Row>() {
                @Override
                public Row[] newArray(int size) {
                    return new Row[size];
                }

                @Override
                public Row createFromParcel(Parcel parcel) {
                    return new Row(parcel);
                }
            };


        ArrayList<String> thumbs;

        public Row(String thumbs) {
            this.thumbs = new ArrayList<String>();
            this.thumbs.add(thumbs);
        }

        public Row(Parcel parcel) {
            parcel.readStringList(thumbs);
        }

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) {
            parcel.writeStringList(thumbs);         
        }

    }
```

**Adapter.java**

```
 private final class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private final List<Row> list;
        private ImageLoader loader;
        private DisplayImageOptions options;

        public ImageAdapter() {
            this(new ArrayList<Row>());

           options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheInMemory()
            .cacheOnDisc()
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .build();

           loader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
           loader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(MainActivity.this));
        }

        public void clear() {
            list.clear();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void add(List<Row> rows) {
            list.addAll(rows);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }



        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public Row getItem(int position) {
            return list.get(position);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup container) {
            if (view == null) {
                view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.grid_item, container, false);
            }

            ImageView image = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageGrid);
            Row row = getItem(position);
            // Bind row on your view here            
            String[] qwe = row.thumbs.toArray(new String[row.thumbs.size()]);
            loader.displayImage(qwe[position], image, options);
            return view;
        }

        public ImageAdapter(List<Row> list) {
            this.list = list;
        }
    }
```

**LogCat**

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
    at com.example.tectob6iu.MainActivity$ImageAdapter.getView(MainActivity.java:98)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
    at android.widget.GridView.makeAndAddView(GridView.java:1341)
    at android.widget.GridView.makeRow(GridView.java:341)
    at android.widget.GridView.fillDown(GridView.java:283)
    at android.widget.GridView.fillFromTop(GridView.java:417)
    at android.widget.GridView.layoutChildren(GridView.java:1229)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1994)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14003)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4375)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14003)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4375)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14003)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4375)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14003)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4375)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1892)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1711)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5191)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Check the length of the list variable , It is only of length 1.

Comment: please give information in English, you will get more help for more people :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
      String[] qwe = row.thumbs.toArray(new String[row.thumbs.size()]);
      loader.displayImage(qwe[position], image, options);
```

are you sure `qwe` contains at least `postion + 1` elements ?

Comment: I change my code success, and now new problem when i click refresh he load new Json and add to this List and LogCat give a error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 23, size is 1